# Ошибка приложения на конкретном устройстве (Galaxy S8, Android 9 SDK 28) / Handler / ZygoteInit

Tags: android, android-sdk, google-play-console, android-9

В Google Play консоли есть вот такая трассировка

```
d.e.d.w: 
  at d.e.d.c0.b0.j$a.a (2)
  at d.e.d.c0.b0.n.a (Unknown Source:2)
  at d.e.d.c0.b0.b$a.a (1)
  at d.e.d.j.a (9)
  at d.f.a.d.b.f (4)
  at d.f.a.h.i.a.a (1)
  at d.f.a.h.i.b.a (56)
  at k.k$b$a$a.run (Unknown Source:37)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7050)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at d.e.d.e0.a.u (Unknown Source:126)
  at d.e.d.c0.b0.o$b0.a (1)
  at d.e.d.c0.b0.j$a.a (1)
```

Но я никак не могу найти в исходнике моего приложения, где могут вызываться данные функции.

И что значит этот тип: `d.e.d.w`

Comment: у вас в build.gradle стоит  minifyEnabled false или true ? есть вероятность что ошибка есть, но названия классов слетели из-за этой пометки, поставьте false если стоит true и ошибка будет с нормальными классами

Comment: вам нужно деобфусцировать ваш лог.

Comment: @Andrew стоит true. Поставил false и теперь не синхронизируется: ERROR: Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on. See http://d.android.com/r/tools/shrink-resources.html for more information.
Affected Modules: app

//поставил shrinkResources false и синхронизирвалось

Comment: Если синхронизация прошла успешно то выложите эту версию и по логике лог будет нормальный, либо потестить релизную версию если получится то найдете ошибку